# Grid class is not working in Tailwind with NextJs, any ideas why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have a problem with the grid classes from Tailwind not doing anything in my code, while every other class (mt-10, flex, etc) work perfectly.

I tried applying flex to the parent container, also taking it out, and so far the closest i've got is with inline-container to make them go one after the other, but they still appear as if they are in a flex setting, not in a grid of 3 columns like I want them (I have 6 photos so I want two rows of 3 and 3)[image: this is how it currently shows (faces blurred for privacy)]

and here's my code:

```
"use client";
import Image from "next/image";
import { MediaStore } from "../Store/mediaStore";

export default function Media() {
  const photos = MediaStore((state) => state.photos);
  return (
    <main
      className=" min-h-screen p-10"
      // style={{ backgroundColor: "green" }}
    >
      <div className="relative flex place-items-center">
        <h1>Media Page</h1>
      </div>

      <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-2 mt-10">
        {photos.map((photo, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="relative inline-block">
            <Image
              className="object-cover"
              width={200}
              height={200}
              src={photo}
              alt={`photo-${index}`}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue does not lay with this component, but is likely a conflicting css property or tailwind configuration issue.

Check that you do not have another .css file that is applying a style to an element in this page, and inspect the tailwind files cover all the filetypes and paths you are using.

Check that the "content" in your tailwind.config.js file is formatted as below or also covers the filetypes and paths you require:

```
  content: [
    './src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
```

note that sometimes people have run into issues where the src/components path was written like the below, causing styles not to be applied:

'./src/components**/.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',

Or they have added new folders which do not have the styles applied because they are not within these paths. (e.g. src/newFolder/newPage.jsx)

Comment: My config file seems to be correct, and as I said, every other Tailwind style works, it's just the grids not working, also, I'm using Tailwind 3.3.5, so, according to documentation, it should be grid-cols-x, so it shouldn't be a typo either.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information then. As this component isn't the issue. Either re-create it in a sandbox to show, or provide more details about your tailwind config and project's paths/layout.
Also, I suggest removing the .map function and manually put 6 images inside the grid grid-cols-3 div and confirm that it works this way. If it does, your issue is with the MediaStore component. If it still does not work, it is likely the tailwind configuration.

Comment: my project has the app folder, and this component is in ./app/media/page.tsx, so it would fall under the ./app/**/* rule of the content that I have on my tailwind config. here's the full config file:


const config: Config = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
 (removed the extra content due to character limitations)

what I don't get is why all the other classes work perfectly, such as the mt-10, but the grid doesn't. If the paths were wrong, none of them would work right?

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure, you need to provide more information or replicate the problem. Incorrect tailwind configuration is the most common cause of the issue you're facing. I have tried to replicate it by various other methods and cannot. 
Either do more testing on your own project to find out if you can make grid-cols work elsewhere or without the MediaStore component dynamically populating the grid, or create your project in a sandbox without sensitive details so that we can inspect further with a bigger picture.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the CSS `grid` classes not compiling with Tailwind and Next.JS

The component path was included in the tailwind `content` config and other classes compiled ok and appeared in the rendered CSS.

The solution in my case was to stop the app, delete the `.next` directory and then start the app again to rebuild it.

After that, the grid classes were added successfully.